# How to unmute video sound when focusing slide on Impress.js

Tags: javascript, video

These are my impress.js slides. 2 of them have videos on them. I'd like to make only the focus slide play sound. Everytime a slide plays, I want the rest of them to mute. Every slide has an iframe with video inside it.

The playlist script for the videos is:

```
function shuffle (array) {
    var i = 0
    , j = 0
    , temp = null

  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
  }
}

function play_vid() {
    video.src = links[current]
    video.play();
    if(current!=links.length) {
        current++;
    }
}

var video = $("#w-video").get(0);
var current = 0;
var links = [];
playlist = $('#playlist');
tracks = playlist.find('li a');

$.each(tracks, function(){
    links.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
shuffle(links);
play_vid();


video.onended = function(e) {
    play_vid();
};
```

The html code for the videos is:

```
<video id="w-video" class="video-js w-video" muted autoplay controls width=640 height=480></video>
   <ul id="playlist">
   <li><a href="https://gemusteste.novohamburgo.rs.gov.br/temp_videos/[SMS]Filme_Mais_Medicos_1min.mp4">Number One</a>
    <li><a href="https://gemusteste.novohamburgo.rs.gov.br/temp_videos/[SMS]FILME_MeningiteC_e_HPV_1min.mp4">Number Two</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

impress.js will emit a impress:stepenter javascript event every time it moves to the next step. You should write an event listener for this event, and in that event listener you then mute/unmute/play/stop your videos. The event.target is the step that was entered. [See the last examples of DOCUMENTATION.md for more info](https://github.com/henrikingo/impress.js/blob/myfork/DOCUMENTATION.md).

```
document.addEventListener( "impress:stepenter", function(event){
    if( event.target.id == "step-1" ) {
        // unmute video 1, mute video 2
    }
    else if( event.target.id == "step-2" ) {
        // unmute video 2, mute video 1
    }
    else {
        // mute both videos
    }
});
```